# Add value into array to get a new value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of integer and a total value.

```
$total = 20;
$array = [1,2,3...];
```

How can I add a $total value on array $array[0] to create a new value and then add the new value into array $array[1] to get new value and store that value into some variable that I can call later?

expected result:

```
$new_total1 = $total + $array[0]
$new_total2 = $new_total1 + $array[1]
and so on...
```

Comment: Please describe what should be final result you need ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in PHP

```
$array = [1,2,3];
$total = 0;
$totals = [];
foreach($array as $index => $num){
    $total += $num;
    $totals[$index] = $total;
}
print_r($totals);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array of the same length if you want to store 'n' different sums. 'n' here is the length of the array.
Then you can run a for loop through the input array and for each element add the previous total, like :-

```
$totalArray = [];
$totalArray[0] = $total + array[0];
for ($i = 1, $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
    $totalArray[i] = $totalArray[i-1] + array[i];
}
```

Comment: You can simply use sizeof($arrayVariable) to get an array's length

Answer (score 0):

HP Array Length can be measured by using either count function or sizeof function

```
$new_total = array();
$total = 20;
$array = [1,2,3...];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    $new_total[$i] = ($i === 0 ? $total : $new_total[$i - 1]) + $array[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code prints the final sum and also stores new values in the new array

```
$newarray=[];
$total=20;
$a=[11,12,53];
$n= count($a);
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
{
$total=$total+ $a[$i];
$newarray[] = $total;
}
print_r($newarray);// new array after sum
echo "<br>Final Total is".$total;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get final sum please try below code

```
 $total = 20;
$array[0] = 1;
$array[1] = 2;
$array[2] = 3;
$array[3] = 4;

foreach($array as $k=> $val){

    $total += $val;
    $new_total1 = $total;
}

print_r($new_total1);
```